# Why do governments in countries with low birth rates tolerate a shortage of kindergartens and elementary schools?

Tags: education

In most of Europe the total fertility rate is lower than the minimum required to sustain the population at its current level. Politicians constantly talk about how we need to keep up the number of people in the productive age, lest our pension and healthcare systems will collapse.

But if increasing the birth rate is seemingly an existential problem for the state, why is there such a shortage of kindergartens and elementary schools in pretty much any European city? Isn't this a big part of why people have less kids?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59700/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-why-do-governments-in-countries-with-low).